# Trouble changing image size in PHP?

Tags: php, image, resize, jpeg, scale

I have the following PHP code...

```
$destination_image_x = "235";  
$destination_image_y = "230";  
$destination_image = imagecreatetruecolor($destination_image_x, $destination_image_y);  
$source_image_x = imagesx($temp_profile_picture_converted);  
$source_image_y = imagesy($temp_profile_picture_converted);  
$temp_profile_picture_converted = imagecopyresampled($destination_image, $temp_profile_picture_converted, 0, 0, 0, 0, $destination_image_x, $destination_image_y, $source_image_x, $source_image_y);  

imagejpeg($temp_profile_picture_converted, $user_profile_picture_filename,'75');  
imagedestroy($temp_profile_picture_converted);
```

The function of this code is to scale an image passed to it, and save it at a specified directory. I'm able to save the image using "imagejpeg" normally if I ommit the resizing snippet. The variable "$temp_profile_picture_converted" is assigned to a jpg image I created from the user's uploaded image with "imagecreatefromjpeg." (Or imagecreatefrompng,  or imagecreatefromgif, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same variable `$temp_profile_picture_converted` twice in the following line. The function `imagecopyresampled()` returns a boolean and is overwriting the image this variable holds. The return value from this function is only to check success. Change it to:

```
if (! imagecopyresampled($destination_image, $temp_profile_picture_converted, 0, 0, 0, 0, $destination_image_x, $destination_image_y, $source_image_x, $source_image_y)){
    // then give error message...
}
```

**UPDATE**
However, you have other errors. You need to change the first parameter of `imagejpeg()`. I also changed the size vars from strings to numbers - not sure if it mattered.

```
imagejpeg($destination_image, $user_profile_picture_filename,75);
```

I successfully ran the following code

```
$destination_image_x = 235;  
$destination_image_y = 230;  

$source_image_x = imagesx($temp_profile_picture_converted);  
$source_image_y = imagesy($temp_profile_picture_converted);

$destination_image = imagecreatetruecolor($destination_image_x, $destination_image_y);  

imagecopyresampled($destination_image, $temp_profile_picture_converted, 0, 0, 0, 0, $destination_image_x, $destination_image_y, $source_image_x, $source_image_y);
imagejpeg($destination_image, $user_profile_picture_filename,75);  
imagedestroy($temp_profile_picture_converted);  
imagedestroy($destination_image);
```

Note that I also added the last statement `imagedestroy($destination_image);`

Comment: Hmmm. I removed the variable declaration from 'imagecopyresampled'. Now my script saves the picture again, however it doesn't resize it. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something. 'imagecopyresampled' will overwrite the source image as the source image overlayed on the destination image, yes? I.E. calling 'imagecopyresampled' simply recreates the picture assigned to '$temp_profile_picture_converted' and assigns the newly created image to the '$temp_profile_picture_converted' variable?

Comment: I updated my answer with tested code. There was another error in the imagejpeg() function call.

Comment: Oops... fixed the line with `imagecopyresampled()` as it had a syntax error created in the copying...